# Validação input via HTML não funciona

Tags: html5

Estou tentando fazer a validação do input usando required e personalizando a mensagem de erro com `oninvalid` porém quando eu preencho o campo que eu tentei submeter sem preencher, pra cada caractere que eu digito ele mostra a mensagem de erro, ou seja o onchange não muda o status do campo.

Alguém saberia me informar o que pode ser isso?

```
 <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Insira o seu nome')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom cara, use validação Regex, é muito mais fácil que colocar javascript, mais rápido e mais leve, vai direto no html.

ex.:

```
<input type="email" required pattern='\w*@\w*\.\w*\.?\w*'>
```

a `pattern` define um padrão, e o código dentro dela é o Regex para validação

comandos básicos do Regex

`\w` = qualquer letra,número e _ (sublinhado/underline)

`\` = define que obrigatóriamente o caractere sucessor  (ex.: '`\.`') deve ser ele mesmo e nenhum outro

`?` = define que o caractere anterior pode ou não ser colocado

Existem outros comandos necessários mas esses são os mais utilizados e facilitam muito, espero ter ajudado :D